# Elasticsearch with ngram indexing not finding partial matches

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, n-gram

So I have an elasticsearch index that was created like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/person' -d '{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type":     "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

On querying for a person named 'ian', I get two results

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/person/_search -d '{
        "query": {
                "match": {
                        "_all": "ian"
                }
        }
}’
```

But on querying for just the letters `ia`, I should get as many or more results, but instead I do not get any:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/person/_search -d '{
        "query": {
                "match": {
                        "_all": "ia"
                }
        }
}’
```

Is something off about my `edge_ngram` filter setup? How can I resolve this?

EDIT: to clarify, I'd like my insert statement to look along the lines of this

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/person/RANDOM_STRING HERE/ANOTHER_RANDOM_STRING" -d "{
 "field1" : "value",
 "field2" : "value",
 "field3" : "value"
}"
```

After inserting, I'd like all fields to be edge_ngram analyzed so that I can search by partial strings by any of those fields and have this result returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to use your analyzer for every type and all properties (unless otherwise specified), you just need to set the "default" analyzer for the index. I'm having trouble finding this in the ES docs (they aren't always terribly user-friendly), but here's an example. I'm using ES 1.5, though I don't think that matters.

```
PUT /person
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 1,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "default": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "autocomplete_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I indexed the docs and ran your query and it worked fine:

```
POST /person/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"Ian"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"Bob Smith"}

POST /person/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "_all": "ia"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1.4142135,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "person",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Ian"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4e2114aafc4f3c507b4f23da8bb83f3ab00e2288

Answer (score 3):

The _all field will use the default analyzer "standard" unless you specify one for it. So the tokens in the _all field are not edge_ngram. Hence no result on searching for "ia". You would generally want to avoid using the _all field for doing a partial match search as it can give unexpected or confusing result.

In case you still need to make use of the _all field then specify the analyzer as "autocomplete" for it also specifically.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this? I'd like set the default mapping for all properties to index everything

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify any types that use your analyzer. So you defined the analyzer, but didn't use it. When you save documents to a new type, the mapping will get defined implicitly, and the [standard analyzer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will be used, which doesn't create partial-word terms, so your search for "ia" doesn't match anything.

One way to handle this is the define your type explicitly, and specify the analyzers you want to use in the mapping. Here is an example, where the index name is "person" (like yours), and the type name is "doc", with a property "name" that uses your analyzer for indexing (but not for searching):

```
PUT /person
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type":     "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc":{
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To test it I added a couple of docs:

```
POST /person/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"Ian"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"Bob Smith"}
```

Then ran a match query against the `"name"` field:

```
POST /person/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "name": "ia"
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "person",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Ian"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test a few different things, including using the `"_all"` field in a way that will make your original query work:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/61df5d17343651884c9422198b6a6bc00a6acb04

Comment: Hmm, the problem with this is that it only works when the type is `doc`, and even then it only works on the `name` property. I'd like this to index every property of every type.

Comment: See my edit where I give a more specific example of how I want the inserts to look

Comment: Oh, haha, that's easy then. Just change the name of your analyzer to "default". I'll post another answer showing that.

Comment: It's always something small like that! Thanks so much!